# Best/common practice to use const string variables or just strings in switch/case c#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, constants

I had the following scenario where an easy fix which jumped to my mind which would have prevented a simple bug.
Following code was presented:

```
var dialogAnswer = new SomeActionSheet("Option 1 as string", "Option 2 as string", "Option 3 as string");

switch(dialogAnswer)
{
    case "Option 1 as string":
        DoSomething();
        break;
    case "Option 2 as string":
        DoSomething();
        break;
}
```

Later on, one answer option string was changed in the dialog, but got forgotten in the switch/case, which resulted in nothing happening, since there was also a "default" case missing.
It came to my mind, that this would have been easily be prevented had I used a variable instead of a string. And since switch/case only allows constants, I would have to use something like:

```
private const string answerOption1 = "Option 1 as string";
```

But if I look in larger projects I never/rarely saw a switch case where constant string variables where used.

So my question is, is this bad practice or just not common and should I use normal strings instead of const variables in switch/cases?
Or would it be even better to use an enum in cases similar to mine?

Comment: "where constant string variables where used." Then you have probably seen the whrong projects. I would stringly suggest to use constants in order to avoid this kind of mistake. Anyway this question is quite opinion-based, there´s no *right* or *whrong* answer here, which is why I´m voting to close it.

Comment: Use constant strings, absolutely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is generally bad practice to use the same string (or any inline value) multiple times in the same project as doing so deviates from the fundamental [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle.

This principle is widely considered a good philosophy to follow until there are reasons why it cannot be employed efficiently in a specific scenario. These could include performance edge-cases or intentional decoupling of dependencies for [share nothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared-nothing_architecture) scenarios. You have not highlighted either of these requirements.

Having a single constant will mitigate errors either when building, refactoring, or deleting code.

Yes you could use an Enum instead of a string. This is also a constant. It also serializes to a number, can be packed as bit flags, and is faster to evaluate than a string of indeterminate length. It also avoids encoding issues.